# Match group again without pasting it again (eg. ABA)

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match a string that has *the same group* in the beginning and in the end, but without repeating *the group* in the pattern.

For simplicity, I'll give an example

Let's assume *the group* is a number, and it appears in the beginning and the end of the string. I want to match `123` and `567`, but only if they are separated by `...`.

`123...567`

An obvious regex would be:

`/([0-9]{3})...([0-9]{3})/`

I want to avoid writing `[0-9]{3}` two times in my regex. The reason is, that in my application, the pattern is much more complex than a simple number. `[0-9]{3}` is in fact a ~100 character long pattern. I want to avoid repeating it to reduce possible errors.

I already read through recursive patterns, but it doesn't seem to match my use case.

So the question is: If and how I can rewrite the pattern above to avoid redundance of my first group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can refer to a subpattern (a capture group) with its number:

```
/([0-9]{3})...((?1))/ 
# or
/([0-9]{3})...(\g<1>)/ # oniguruma syntax
```

or you can use a relative reference too:

```
/([0-9]{3})...(?-1)/ # -1 means the last opened capture group on the left
/([0-9]{3})...\g<-1>/ # (oniguruma)
# or if there's an other opened capture group:

/([0-9]{3})...((?-2))/
```

When you have a long pattern with several subpatterns, using named captures can be more handy:

```
/(?<mycap>[0-9]{3})...(\g<mycap>)/
```

and when you have a more complicated pattern, you can include a definition section, where subpatterns are defined (as a kind of lexer), before the "real" main pattern:

```
/ # subpattern definitions:
 (?(DEFINE)
    (?<mycap>[0-9]{3})
    (?<anothersubpattern> [A-Z]{2,4}:[0-9]{4} )
    etc.
 )

  # main pattern
(\g<mycap>) ... (\g<mycap>)
/x
```

Note: php accepts several syntaxes to refer to a subpattern: `\g<mycap>`, `(?&mycap)` are equivalent. In the same way, you can define a named subpattern with different syntaxes: `(?<mycap> ...)`, `(?'mycap' ...)`, `(?P<mycap> ...)`

To avoid confusions:

```
(?1), (?-1), \g<1>, \g<-1>, (?&mycap), \g<mycap> refer to subpatterns

\1, \g{1}, \g{-1}, \k<mycap>, \g{mycap} refer to captured content
```

Comment: @karthikmanchala: The answer is correct. `\g<mycap>` is an Oniguruma compatible behavior (as far as I remember)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I knew I could name capturing groups, but always thought it just makes accessing the results easier. But this is an invaluable insight. Appreciated!

Comment: @Philipp: an other important point is that you can use them to build recursive patterns: `(?<nestedcurly>{[^{}]*(?:\g<nestedcurly>[^{}]*)*+})` (as you can see circular references are not a problem (if it stops before the max recursion level is reached))